# DIsplay multiple lines using plotHR() function from Greg package in R

Tags: r, spline, cox-regression

I want to display multiple lines in a graph showing the Hazard ratio from a Cox regression model on the y-axis and age as restricted cubic splines (rcs) with 4 df on the x-axis. Each line should be based on the other adjustment factors, i.e. one for sex and one for smoking. In the reproducible example below, it only displays one line, and not stratified by sex and smoking status (thus should be four lines).

My question is, how to do this using plotHR() from the Greg package? In the documentation about plotHR it states:

This function is a more specialized version of the termplot() function. It creates a plot with the spline against hazard ratio. The plot can additianally have indicator of variable density and have multiple lines.

```
# NOT RUN {
library(survival)
library(rms)
library(splines)

# Get data for example
n <- 1000
set.seed(731)

age <- round(50 + 12 * rnorm(n), 1)
label(age) <- "Age"

sex <- factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), n,
  rep = TRUE, prob = c(.6, .4)
))
cens <- 15 * runif(n)

smoking <- factor(sample(c("Yes", "No"), n,
  rep = TRUE, prob = c(.2, .75)
))

# Build outcome
h <- .02 * exp(.02 * 
                 (age - 50) + .1 * 
                 ((age - 50) / 10)^3 + .8 * 
                 (sex == "Female") + 2 * 
                 (smoking == "Yes"))
dt <- -log(runif(n)) / h
label(dt) <- "Follow-up Time"

e <- ifelse(dt <= cens, 1, 0)
dt <- pmin(dt, cens)
units(dt) <- "Year"

# Add missing data to smoking
smoking[sample(1:n, round(n * 0.05))] <- NA

# Create a data frame since plotHR will otherwise
# have a hard time getting the names of the variables
ds <- data.frame(
  dt = dt,
  e = e,
  age = age,
  smoking = smoking,
  sex = sex
)

dd <- datadist(ds)
options(datadist = "dd")
fit.cph <- cph(Srv ~ rcs(age, 4) + sex + smoking, data = ds, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

plotHR(fit.cph,
       term = 1,
       plot.bty = "l",
       xlim = c(30, 70),
       xlab = "Age")

plotHR(fit.cph, 
       term = "age", 
       plot.bty = "l", 
       xlim = c(30, 70),
       ylog = FALSE,
       rug = "ticks",
       xlab = "Age")
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide both models as a list:

```r
f1 <- cph(Surv(dt, e) ~ rcs(age, 4) + sex + smoking, data = ds, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
f2 <- update(f1, . ~ rcs(age, 4))

plotHR(list(f1, f2),
       term = 1,
       plot.bty = "l",
       xlim = c(30, 70),
       xlab = "Age")
```